# JavaScript ternary operator doesn't accept rest parameters?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

In trying to use the ternary operator to conditionally pass one of two arguments to the slice method of string like so:

```
var str = "abcdefg";
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
str.slice(a > b ? ...[b, a] : ...[a, b]);
```

I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..."

Am I doing something wrong in my use of ternary op & rest together? Is there a right way to write this expression? Or, as a developer friend claims, is this a fault in the implementation of either rest parameters or the ternary operator?

Ternary operator in the argument to the method works without rest parameters:

```
str.slice(a > b ? a : b)
```

And rest parameter works without the ternary operator:

```
str.slice(...[a, b])
```

I'm doing all this in the Chrome console. Also tried all the same lines with array.slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `...` operator is part of array literals or call expressions; it doesn't make any sense as a standalone operator (what would `...a` mean standalone?).

You can apply it to any method call, as long as you actually apply to the parameter:

```
str.slice(...(a > b ? [b, a] : [a, b]));
```

Comment: @NinaScholz: That's why he's using the spread operator to not pass an array.

Comment: @NinaScholz: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Thank you @SLaks for showing me the right way, but I still don't understand _why_ that's the way. When you say ... doesn't make any sense standalone are you saying that my expression a > b ? ...[b, a] : ...[a, b] somehow returns a standalone ... separate from [a, b]? I don't see why it wouldn't evaluate a > b and then pass ...[b, a] as arg to the method (which is what I want)

Comment: `...[b, a]` doesn't make sense as a thing that you can write anywhere and pass as an argument (what would that thing be?).  `...` only applies to syntax of the method call.

Comment: ok, I just played around with ternary in other contexts, such as assigning to an array, and I think I understand. You're saying that the ternary is a context for the `...` separate and apart from the context of the method call, and that `...` doesn't make sense in that context? And that's because spread only makes sense in a small number of specific contexts?